# What plant is it?

Tags: identification, weeds, outdoor

I got a plant growing very tall next to a rose.

Not sure what plant is it as it is different from the regular weed.

Here are some images of the plant overview and a closer photoshot of the plant leave:
[image][image][image]

It does not show any flower before so I wonder if this is a weed?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you live in Europe, I would say it is a common ash (*Fraxinus excelsior*). If you live in the new World, it is probably a relative (I am not very familiar with new world tree species and their distribution).

You might want to consider if that is the right place for a tree to grow, ashes can become quite big.

Comment: That *isn't* the right place for it. I agree it looks like an ash, and it has just reached the stage where it will grow about 10 or 20 feet taller per year for the next 4 or 5 years! If there is an ash tree anywhere within 100 yards of your house, you can expect more seedlings every year when the seeds get blown about by the wind. Ash trees look great in the right place, but except for small species like rowan (mountain ash) a garden is *not* the right place for them.